# How to make Game Over UI pop up after a collision?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, screen

I am making a game where, if the catcher gets destroyed by the object, the game over screen is triggered. All that seems to occur is that there is a giant game over the screen at the beginning of when I play, while the game is running in the background. For some reason, the game does not seem to call in the game over screen only on collision.
This is the script I am using for my catcher, where it collides, disappears, and then the game over screen is set up to be triggered.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class CatcherDestroy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameOverScreen GameOverScreen;
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Catcher"))
        {
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
            GameOverScreen;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the code for my GameOverScreen.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameOverScreen : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text pointsText;

    public void Setup(int score) 
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(true);
        pointsText.text = "Score:" + score.ToString(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling anything when an object collides, you're just listing the reference of the object. You'll need to call the function that you have exposed. Without calling a method from the script reference, no code will be run. Edit your first snippet as follows:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class CatcherDestroy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameOverScreen GameOverScreen;
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Catcher"))
        {
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
            GameOverScreen.Setup();
        }
    }
}
```

The other option would be to move the code in `Setup` to `Awake` or `Start` or `OnEnable`, then instead of calling the function in the collision, you just need to set it as active.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class CatcherDestroy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameOverScreen GameOverScreen;
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Catcher"))
        {
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
            GameOverScreen.score = theScore;
            GameOverScreen.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameOverScreen : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text pointsText;
    public int score;
    
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        pointsText.text = "Score:" + score.ToString(); 
    }
}
```

The one issue is you'll need to pass in the `score` parameter which I do not see in your script `CatcherDestroy`.